# dump object to String with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, gson

I'm using Gson to generate debug ouput in my application

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
gson.toJson(myObject);
```

But Gson does complain about a circular reference error when attempting to serialize a data structure.
Can this be done with Jackson library?

**UPD**
Gson 2.3.1: Released Nov 20, 2014

```
Added support to serialize objects with self-referential fields. The self-referential field is set to null in JSON. Previous version of Gson threw a StackOverflowException on encountering any self-referential fields.
    The most visible impact of this is that Gson can now serialize Throwable (Exception and Error)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To serialize with Jackson:

```
public String serialize(Object obj, boolean pretty) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);

    if (pretty) {
        return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
    }

    return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
}
```

Comment: the first argument of configure() method should be `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` currently. Your serialize() method should have `throws JsonProcessingException` or try/catch block

Comment: My configure lines ended up being like this:
`mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);`

Answer (score 11):

Jackson can deal with cycles in the object graph with:

1. [`@JsonIgnore`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html), where you omit the property entirely
2. [`@JsonManagedReference`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonManagedReference.html) and [`@JsonBackReference`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonBackReference.html)
3. a custom Serializer which extends [`JsonSerializer`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html)

You would use `JsonSerializer` when you still wish to provide some information about the object but want to omit certain fields (the ones causing the cycle). For example:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ParentReferenceSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Parent> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Parent parent, JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        writeNumberField(jgen, "id", parent.getId());
        // ... other fields ...
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then in the class in which is being serialized, you'd use a `@JsonSerialize` annotation:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ParentReferenceSerializer.class)
public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
}
```