# How can I return child objects in a many-to-many relationship with Dropwizard/Hibernate/Swagger without recursion?

Tags: jackson, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard and Swagger to create a REST API to manage access to various objects. Two of these objects are involved in a many-to-many relationship, for example:

```
public class Puppy implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Trick.class)
    @JoinTable(
        name="puppies_tricks",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="puppy_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="trick_id"))
    private List<Trick> tricks;

    @JsonProperty("tricks")
    public List<Trick> getTricks() { return this.tricks; }
    ...
}    

public class Trick implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Puppy.class)
    @JoinTable(
        name="puppies_tricks",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="trick_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="puppy_id"))
    private List<Puppy> puppies;

    @JsonProperty("puppies")
    public List<Puppy> getPuppies() { return this.puppies; }
    ...
}
```

And suppose the actual data looks something like:

```
# Tricks:
[{ id: 1, name: 'Roll over' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Play dead' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Steal second' }]

# Puppies:
[{ id: 1, name: 'Flopsy' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Mopsy' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Cottontail' }]

# Puppies_Tricks
[{ puppy_id: 1, trick_id: 1 },
{ puppy_id: 1, trick_id: 2 },
{ puppy_id: 2, trick_id: 2 },
{ puppy_id: 2, trick_id: 3 }]
```

So when I GET /puppy/1 I want to get a structure like:

```
{ 
  "id": 1, 
  "name": "Flopsy", 
  "tricks": [ 
    { "id": 1, "name": "Roll over"}, 
    { "id": 2, "name": "Play dead" } ]
}
```

but what I'm actually getting is a nested array:

```
{ 
  "id": 1, 
  "name": "Flopsy", 
  "tricks": [ 
    { "id": 1, "name": "Roll over", "puppies": [ { "id": 1, "name": "Flopsy" }, ...}, 
    { "id": 2, "name": "Play dead", "puppies": [...] } ]
}
```

Is there some way to tell Jackson/Dropwizard to stop descending through tricks to when getting puppies, and vice versa?

Dropwizard 1.0.6, Java 1.8.

Comment: Could you explain *stop descending through tricks to when getting puppies, and vice versa?* a little further(simpler) please.

Comment: Added more info to clarify. The essential problem is that, when querying for a puppy, I want a list of that puppy's tricks only, and I don't want to then see the list of which other puppies can perform each given trick.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9768357/25429 is a summary with the possible approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson has support of object-graph serialization through the `@JsonManagedReference @JsonBackReference` annotations. See [the documentation here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#object-references-identity). You can find a [simple example here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion).
You should **really** read more carefully the documentation of the tools you're using.

There is already [an answer that summarizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9768357/25429) what approaches are available.

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonIgnore
@JsonProperty("puppies")
public List<Puppy> getPuppies() { return this.puppies; }
```

will stop infinite loop

Comment: explain your answer?

Comment: it will, but then it means that when I GET /tricks/:id there's no corresponding list of puppies. Which I actually want.

I'm starting to think the solution is to do as you suggest and provide a separate /tricks/:id/puppies endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

My solution here was to create a separate PuppyCore class that implements serialization but isn't persisted. This includes basic Puppy info (id, name). Similarly a TrickCore has id and name only.

Then Puppy includes Set tricks, with this getter:

```
public Set<TrickCore> getTricks();
```

which returns a list of TrickCore objects – these don't have the Puppy list, and so halts the recursion. A similar pattern on Trick returns `Set<PuppyCore>` for `getPuppies()`.