# Convert JsonObject to Json String with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson and am able to get a `JSONObject`. I need to be able to convert this `JSONObject` to its `json` form. Meaning, the object that is represented by this `JSONObject`'s son string.

Something like:

```
JsonObject object = ...;
object.toJsonString();
```

A simple Google search surprisingly didn't turn up many response and I am unable to see how to do it on my own.

Any ideas?

Comment: So basically [dump object to String with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767131/dump-object-to-string-with-jackson)?

Comment: @dhke No, thats an object. In this case, its already been parsed.

Comment: Hrm... wouldn't that be an `ObjectNode` in Jackson?

Comment: @dhke I do have access to it as an ObjectNode as well. But the problem is, how do I get that back to a son string representation

Comment: I don't understand. Jackson doesn't have a `JsonObject` or a `JSONObject` type. What type are you talking about? Jackson's `ObjectNode`'s `toString` method results in its JSON representation.

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
JSONObject object = ...;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Comment: This outputs `"{"empty":false}"` for me. I'm using Jackson 2.11.4. What could be wrong?

Comment: did you get any solution for "{"empty":false}" ? I am facing similar issue

Comment: @Olov Srikar I am getting response like this {"map": object, "empty":false}  in response. I am getting additional "empty" key and "map" key, and the value of map is coming as actual object. I have tried on the latest version of 2.15.0. and same error
Any way how we can remove this "map" and "empty" key ?

Comment: somewhat late but anyway: this seems to be the output of an Optional. try to pass in `<myOptional>.get()`

Answer (score 0):

```
  StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
  object.writeJSONString(out);

  String jsonText = out.toString();
  System.out.print(jsonText);
```

Comment: Yea, it appears `org.json.JSONObject` doesn't have a write method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to bridge the 2 APIs you can create a custom StdSerializer.
More on custom serializers:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

```
private static class JSONObjectSerializer extends StdSerializer<JSONObject> {

    JSONObjectSerializer(){
        this(null);
    }

    JSONObjectSerializer(Class<JSONObject> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override public void serialize(JSONObject value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        value.keys().forEachRemaining(key-> {
            try {
                gen.writeStringField(key,value.getString(key));
            } catch (IOException ex){
                throw new RuntimeException("Encountered an error serializing the JSONObject.",ex);
            }
        });
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    private static SimpleModule toModule(){
        return new SimpleModule().addSerializer(JSONObject.class, new JSONObjectSerializer());
    }
}

//.......

ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper()
    .registerModule(JSONObjectSerializer.toModule())
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();

//.......

try {
    s = w.writeValueAsString(v);// v being your JSONObject or parent
} catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to write object to json.", ex);
}
```